# Train test split a list of sentence

Tags: python

I have a list of sentences. I want to randomly separate into 80% and 20%, it looks like this:

```
['Hi.',
 'Hi.',
 'Run!',
 'Wow!',
 'Wow!',
 'Fire!',
 'Help!',
 'Help!',
 'Stop!',
 'Wait!',
 'Go on.',
 'Hello!',
 'I ran.',
 'I see.',
 'I see.',
 'I try.',
 'I won!',...]
```

I was thinking using a mask

```
import random
mask = [0] * 4000 + [1] * 16000
random.shuffle(mask)
```

But it is not like a data frame.
and I tried

```
percent=80
bol_mask =[random.randrange(100) < percent for i in range(100)]
```

Cant really apply boolean to sentences

Also the separation mask must be kept, and will later apply to another list in German, which is the corresponding translation.

it looks like this

```
array([[ 553,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3430, 1114,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [1115,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3431,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3432,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [2459,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3433,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [1533, 3434,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [2460,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [ 394,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0]],
      dtype=int32)
```

My question is how to apply mask to a list of sentences? and keep the same split and apply to the corresponding ndarray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `scikit-learn` is an option, you can just use [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) method as the following:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> print(x)
>>> x
['Hi.', 'Hi.', 'Run!', 'Wow!', 'Wow!', 'Fire!', 'Help!', 'Help!', 'Stop!', 'Wait!']

>>> len(x)
10
>>>  x1
array([[ 553,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3430, 1114,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [1115,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3431,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3432,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [2459,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3433,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [1533, 3434,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [2460,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [ 394,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0]])
>>> x1.shape
(10, 20)

#assuming x, x1 have same length train test split should work fine.
>>> train, test, train_german, test_german = train_test_split(x,x1, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
>>> len(train)
8
>>> len(test)
2
>>> len(train_german)
8
>>> len(test)
2
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please consider accepting/check-marking the answer.

Comment: but how do you keep the same split for the other list? I have a corresponding translation in German.
its  a padded nd array, looks like this-
array([[ 553,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [3430, 1114,    6,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],


      dtype=int32)   it will need a corresponding split

Comment: actually not really, it comes back with Error

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-69440e854a45> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 2 train,test = train_test_split(Eng, padded,test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've solved it my self.

```
bol_mask =[random.randrange(100) < 80 for i in range(20000)]
inv_mask = np.invert(bol_mask)

Eng_train =np.array(Eng)[bol_mask]
Eng_test =np.array(Eng)[inv_mask]
German_train = padded[bol_mask]
German_test = padded[inv_mask]
```

Thanks Grayrigel, an accept for your effort in helping

Comment: I have updated the answer. would love to know if it works for you.